# automate substitute in Visual mode

Tags: vimrc

I would like automating the following in my .vimrc:

```
:'<,'>s/ \+| \+/|/g
```

With something like the following but it does not work:

```
vmap <Leader>rt :s/ \+| \+/|/g<CR>
```

it seems the whitespace has to be escaped, I tried \s but there is another warning. What is the easiest solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<space>` to describe a space, although it is not mandatory.
However, `|` has to be escaped: `\|`

the result would be: `vmap <Leader>rt :s/ \+\| \+/\|/g<cr>` (or `vmap <Leader>rt :s/<space>\+\|<space>\+/\|/g<cr>` with `<space>`)

On top of it, I'd suggest to use `vnoremap`, unless you actively need a recursive mapping.

Comment: Well, xnoremap, unless you need select mode. And theoretically `<space>` is unnecessary here.

Comment: Indeed, editing.

Comment: You might want to add a reference to [`:help map-bar`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-bar), which explains why this is needed here.